# Context AddAsync + SaveChangesAsync => Double await?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asynchronous, async-await

What do you think about using async + await two times in a row when using EF Core in WEB-API .NET Core webapp?

```
await _context.Teams.AddAsync(newTeam);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

return newTeam.TeamId;
```

Does it makes sense? I want code of creating new Team to be async safe. But should I use "**AddAsync + SaveChangesAsync**" or is the "**Add + SaveChangesAsync**" safe as well?

What do you think? Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://thesharperdev.com/ef-cores-addasync-v-add-method/ - summary: use `AddAsync`. You probably don't need it, but it won't hurt.

Comment: Either of them could result in a database roundtrip. Therefore both should be async.

Comment: *"I want code of creating new Team to be async safe."* -- What do you mean be that? What "async safe" means in this context?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use both. Please pass the `CancellationToken` from the controller down to both methods, so you that you have

```
await _context.Teams.AddAsync(newTeam, ct);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync(ct);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.addasync?view=efcore-6.0

This way, you can save calculation time if the request is aborted.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how this `CancellationToken` is created in the controller before being passed down to the EF code?

Comment: @silkfire Just add "CancellationToken ct = default" as parameter to your controller method

Comment: That sounds rather pointless, `default` means no timeout so you could just as well leave it out.